# Showing a function is measurable, namely, the function $f(x) = x$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am currently following the text Real Analysis by Royden, and after he introduces the definition of a (Lebesgue) measurable function he just lists propositions and such with no *explicit* example of a measurable function. One of the propositions he shows that every continuous real-valued function on a measurable domain is measurable. So, my question is: how would you show *explicitly*, i.e. without any proposition, that the function $f(x) = x$ on a measurable domain, say $E$, is a measurable function? Below I will included the definition of a (Lebesgue) measurable function:

**Definition:** A function $f$ is said to be (Lebesgue) measurable function on a measurable domain $E$ if, for each real number $c$, the set $\{x \in E: f(x) > c\}$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\{x\in E: f(x)>c\}=\{x\in E: x>c\}=E\,\cap (c,\infty)$. Clearly both $E$ and $(c,\infty)$ are measurable and sigma-algebras are closed under intersection. The set $E$ is given to be measurable. The set $(c,\infty)$ is open. Therefore, it is an element of the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B},$ which is contained in $\mathcal{M}$, the sigma-algebra associated with Lebesgue measurable sets.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much :)

Comment: As a remark, I'm not sure where you're at in your studies. Is it accepted that intervals are Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Yes. That was in the previous chapter over measurable sets.